# How I can set a size of message (PDU) for the Californium server?

Tags: iot, coap, californium

How I can set a size of PDU dynamically for `Californium` server?

Context:

1) I have a device with implemented `coap-client` functionality.
This device is constrained by `RAM`, about 200 free bytes for `rx/tx` buffers.

In the request the device can sent a prefer PDU size. But I don't understand how to configure server responses with this PDU size. Is it possible?

2) Will be work a blockwise-functionality for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found how to do it.

It is not a `Californium` responsibility. The management of the PDU-size works via `block-wise` option `Block2`.

See the [CoAP block-wise RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7959) `Section 3.1`:

> In the second example (Figure 3), the client anticipates the block-
> wise transfer (e.g., because of a size indication in the link-format
> description [RFC6690]) and sends a block size proposal.  All ACK
> messages except for the last carry 64 bytes of payload; the last one
> carries between 1 and 64 bytes.

```
Client                                                   Server
|                                                          |
| CON [MID=1234], GET, /status, 2:0/0/64           ------> |
|                                                          |
| <------   ACK [MID=1234], 2.05 Content, 2:0/1/64         |
|                                                          |
| CON [MID=1235], GET, /status, 2:1/0/64           ------> |
|                                                          |
| <------   ACK [MID=1235], 2.05 Content, 2:1/1/64         |
:                                                          :
:                          ...                             :
:                                                          :
| CON [MID=1238], GET, /status, 2:4/0/64           ------> |
|                                                          |
| <------   ACK [MID=1238], 2.05 Content, 2:4/1/64         |
|                                                          |
| CON [MID=1239], GET, /status, 2:5/0/64           ------> |
|                                                          |
| <------   ACK [MID=1239], 2.05 Content, 2:5/0/64         |

    Figure 3: Block-Wise GET with Early Negotiation
```